# Searching a file name with just part of file name known

Tags: batch-file

I have searched the entire forum but couldn't find what i was looking for.
I have few file's in a folder i know just a part of the file name. Example `stackoverflow_newuser_6.2.txt` and `stackoverflow_olduser_6.2.txt`. I know that file name contains olduser and newuser.

How can i search for file based on substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming windows:

```
dir /s /b *newuser*
```

Or if you need to do something usefull with the found filename:

```
for /R %t in (*newuser*) do echo %~nt
```

Or with the full path

```
for /R %t in (*newuser*) do echo %t
```

Comment: This solution is finding the file but i just need the output to be filename. It should echo just file name.